# pandas pivot table: dropna does not create new column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a data frame with two columns: df._merge and df.A.
df.A is an object column with a few values and NA.

When trying to output pairs and their count with `pivot_table` I am missing the na values, and using `dropna=False` in `pivot_table` does not return them.

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    '_merge':['left_only', 'both','right_only', 'right_only'],
    'A':['1', '1','2',pd.NA]
})

df.pivot_table(index='_merge', columns='A', aggfunc='size', fill_value='-', dropna=False)
```

returns pivot without NA values:

[image]

but manually filling na's shows that they are there:

```
df['fA'] = dffff.A.fillna('NA')
df.pivot_table(index='_merge', columns='fA', aggfunc='size', fill_value='-', dropna=False)
```

[image]

How can I get the pivot with empty values in pivot columns without having to create a new column in the source df?

Comment: The best I can think of is to pass the filled column to `pivot_table` directly: `df.pivot_table(index='_merge', columns=df.A.fillna('NA'), aggfunc='size', fill_value='-')`.

Comment: That will work but I don’t understand why the dropna arg isn’t

Comment: I believe the `dropna` is only for dropping columns whose values are all NaN after the pivoting, not for making sure that NaN values are preserved in the columns that are being used as `index` and `columns` kwargs to pivot_table.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with the following code:

```
df.groupby(['_merge','A'], dropna=False).size().unstack().fillna('-')
```

This preserves the NAN values

[image: pandas dataframe]